# All users can sign in use azure spring security

Tags: java, azure, spring-security

I've prepared an application that uses microsoft azure login. Currently security settings require me to enter a group with users who have access to log in. How to configure active directory so that every email can log in to the application?

```
    azure:
      activedirectory:
        tenant-id: mytenatId
        user-group:
           allowed-groups: Users
```

I used this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory#add-a-user-account-to-your-directory-and-add-that-account-to-a-group

How to configure it so that any user can log in with microsoft and not just those added in the group?

Comment: Hi, does it solve your issue? If it works, you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=Users` from the `application.properties` file, also remove the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('')")` related stuff from your code.